# How to return a radius/key-word search of my data using Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude, android-maps-v2

I am building a Android app using the Google Maps Android API v2.

I have a database of lat/long that Im trying to search and display, either by radius(in miles) and/or key-word based on my current location.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your problem btw?

Comment: what do you want to search and display ? Places associated with these lat/lngs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would approach it:

1. Get the users location in lat/long
2. User the haversine formula to compute the distance to points already
   in your database.
3. Filter out the points that meet your threshold criterea (less than 5
   miles for example)
4. Within the GoogleMaps class, look at the addMarker() method. Use
   this to add your filtered database lat/long to the map.

A similar approach with keywords, you filter by keyword and not haversine distance.